# Speed up execution of Java 11 single-file "scripts"

Tags: java, java-11

In Java 11, you can run a single class file with a main class like a script.

For example, take a file called `n`:

```
#!java --source 11

public class n {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

We can now call it from command line with `./n` (assuming it's executable after a `chmod +x`).

The problem is, even this single print statement takes a considerable amount of time to run. On average, according to `time` it's taking roughly ~1.2 seconds to run.

Is there any way to speed this up? I presume it's the compiling - is there any way to cache the compiled class and only recompile on file change, or something like that? Or is my dream of writing simple, fast, re-runnable scripts in Java still not attainable? :(

Comment: jvm start up time is a known con for using java

Comment: Hi perhaps make a request to an already-running Java application server in your command-line script

Comment: Take a look at Graal [Native Image](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/aot-compilation/).